# Eclipse-applet into html page

Tags: java, html, eclipse, applet

I am trying to import my applet into a html page within eclipse,

when I am try to run the html page there is an error that says

```
"incompatible magic value 218787937 in class file defaultPackage/StreamingApplet"
```

I have tried to resolve this myself through clearing the internet files is which a few people had suggest but this did not help.

any ideas Thanks?

Comment: So let me get this straight.  You have an applet with package statement:- `package defaultPackage;`?  (Package names should be all lower case, BTW.)

Comment: cheers ill see if it helps, but the applet works fine when run as an applet its when i try to embed it in a html page is when the error is happening